# New to r, trying to run a mixed effects anova, unsure how to structure data and run test

Tags: anova

I am using R studio and I am trying to run a mixed effects ANOVA on my data. The data consists of 6 subjects. 3 in condition A, 3 in condition B. Each subject has 19 to 25 observations (example: subject 1 has condition A and has been sampled 20 times). I am new to r so would love some help.

I currently have my data in table format with the 2 conditions as labels. Looks like below.

A   A    A      B     B      B

.1  .2
.3
.3